# Capturing an HTTP Post request with garbled body

Tags: post, encoding, request

I am using Postman to capture a HTTP Post request, but the body in the captured post is garbled:

```
POST /account/login HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/x-java-serialized-object
system: android
appPlatform: android
language: en-us
lid: 
licenseId: 
email: 
timestamp: 1599332016
token: 
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 10; MI 9 MIUI/V12.0.2.0.QFAMIXM)
Host: 
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 192

t §»~ַa¼::,טשf­¢ §—^ת
÷×’buַת״MBEָ,×œ•ן‘Za(קH¢;J±…JD+13}D-’Šwrb~ֱ/ת$^›#+רתµO†ַR–עm>K¿^‚^}lSa־#tGzE:PXf9'?po>„«Eֲרֽן ‹l¡x
ָ^§ב•ח£¯1,xbז³ג<–¦IzJחםם"“דל1#ױ S
```

If I try to send the same post with the same body, I get an error. Is there a way to capture the actual body text?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue, the body was in binary format. I saved it as bin and attached it to the request I made through Postman and it worked.